# Printing a string of 'n' characters by repeating a string

Tags: java, string, loops, int

This is for my revision. I'm trying to build a string of `int n` characters by repeating `String s`. The answer I'm trying to get is `testtestte`.

This is what I have so far. When index reaches 4, it would obviously be out or bound as the string has only 4 characters. I want it so that when index reaches 3 it goes back to 0 and continues on until int n satisfies(this might be the wrong word to use) 10. Sorry if the question isn't clear enough.

```
  public static void main(String[] args){

    beads("test", 10);

  }

 public static void beads(String s, int n){

    char[] eachChar = new char[n];
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
      eachChar[index] = s.charAt(index);
    }
    System.out.println(eachChar);

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is to modulo the index by the length of the string:

```
  eachChar[index] = s.charAt(index % s.length());
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use mod (%) operator.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    beads("test", 10);
}

public static void beads(String s, int n){
    char[] eachChar = new char[n];
    for (int index = 0; index < n; index++) {
        eachChar[index] = s.charAt(index%s.length());
    }
    System.out.println(eachChar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a way easier and lazier way

```
    String in = "test";
    int len = 10;

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    while (buf.length() < len) {
        buf.append(in);
    }
    System.out.println(buf.substring(0, len));
```

Always try to find an easier way to do things as in the end there will be less bugs

Answer (score 0):

Going for the fastest approach is to use arrayCopy , to copy values to array in bouts . This is the same method used by "string/stringbuilder etc .." internally 
below is how to use it

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            timesRepeat("test",30);
        }
        public static void  timesRepeat(String input , int times )
        {
            char[] resultString = new char[times];
            //write in bouts 

            int fullPart = times/input.length();
            int partPart = times%input.length();
            for ( int i =0 ; i< fullPart; i++)
            {
                System.arraycopy(input.toCharArray(), 0, resultString, (i*input.length()), input.length());
            }

            System.arraycopy(input.toCharArray(), 0, resultString, (fullPart)*input.length(), partPart);
            System.out.println(resultString);
        }
```